# Mongodb aggregation query to java code

Tags: aggregation-framework, mongo-java-driver

Can someone help me telling if the java code for the following query using Aggregates is correct or not?

Mongo DB Shell Query:

```
        db.getCollection('xyz').aggregate([
          {
            $match: {
              "try.Ind": "A",
              "_id.a": "AC",
              "_id.b": "HXYZ",
              "_id.c": "12345678",
              "_id.d": "AA",
              "_id.e": "2018-03-09"
            }
          },
          {
            $project: {
              "try": 1,
              total: {
                $sum: {
                  $map: {
                    input: {
                      $filter: {
                        input: "$try",
                        cond: {
                          $and: [
                            {
                              $eq: [
                                "$$this.Ind",
                                "A"
                              ]
                            },
                            {
                              $lt: [
                                "$$this.mt",
                                0.0
                              ]
                            }
                          ]
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    "in": "$$this.mt"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        ])
```

Java Code:

I have used the Bson filter inorder to match all my conditions in the query.

```
Bson filter = and(eq("try.Ind","A"),eq("_id.a","AC"),eq   ("_id.b","HXYZ"),eq("_id.c","12345678"),eq("_id.d","AA"),eq("_id.e","2018-03-09"));

AggregateIterable<Document> aggDocument=collectionName.aggregate(
        Arrays.asList( 
        Aggregates.match(filter),
        Aggregates.project(
        Projections.fields(Projections.include("try"),
        new Document("total",
        new Document("$sum", 
        new Document("$map",
        new Document("input",
        new Document("$filter",
        new Document("input","$try").
        append ("cond",new Document("$and",Arrays.asList(
        new Document("$eq",Arrays.asList("$$this.Ind","A")),
        new Document("$lt",Arrays.asList(
        "$$this.mt",0.0))))))).append("in","$$this.mt"))))))));
```

Please help me correcting if anything is wrong in the above code.
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Looks correct. Is this not working for you ?

Comment: Its working...Just needed a confirmation weather am I going correct or nt.Thanks@Veeram

Comment: This is correct.

Comment: thanks alot  :) @Veeram